# How to connect client with MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I was trying to connect my client with MongoDB, but I got an error: `MongoParseError: option useunifedtopology is not supported`. I don't know why this is happening, I will be very grateful for your help, this is my code:

```
const { Databse } = require("../../config.json");

module.exports = {
    name: "ready",
    once: true,
    execute(client) {
        console.log("The client is now ready!");

        if(!Databse) return;
        mongoose.connect(Databse, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifedTopology: true
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("The client is now connected with the Database!")
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }    
}
```

Comment: The option is spelled wrong, it should be `useUnifiedTopology`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, the error is caused due to a typo. Please just, before posting a question, go through your code to see if there are any potential typos here and there. Here, when calling the `mongoose.connect()` function you are giving it an option called `useUnifedTopology` without an 'i' in the 'unifed'. So, you can just correct that and you should be good to go